# Prove that infinitely many instances of ZF schemata are necessary in ZF

Tags: set-theory

I want to prove that infinitely many instances of the ZF schemata (**Separation**, **Replacement**) are needed in ZF, i.e. that no finite subset $S$ of their instances is such that $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Separation} - \textbf{Replacement} + S \vdash \textbf{ZF}$.

My strategy: construct a "finitary" version of the Gödel constructible universe $L^-$ allowing only sets constructible by the finitely many axioms in $\textbf{ZF} - \textbf{Separation}- \textbf{Replacement} + S$. Then show there is a ZF set not in $L^-$.

But the second step is proving harder than I thought.
Surely there is a standard example of this that I am missing -- does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A lot of the time, *no* instances of separation are necessary since they can be derived from replacement... but that's sensitive to how you phrase the axioms. So, it would be good if you would add exactly what the axioms you are using are.

Comment: Given your claim in the "strategy" paragraph that $\mathsf{ZF-Separation}$ is finite, maybe you want to throw out $\mathsf{Separation}$ **and** [$\mathsf{Replacement}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber you're right that's what I want

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you; edited. What happens if we throw both Separation and Replacement out except for finitely many of their instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is the [**reflection theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#In_ZFC), which says that for every finite subtheory $A\subset \mathsf{ZF}$ there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models A$. This lets us prove the non-finite-axiomatizability of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in two ways, one set-theoretic and the other proof-theoretic. (Incidentally, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3990838/28111) for another example of such a proof/set argument divide.)

*(Recall that the reflection theorem is proved outside $\mathsf{ZF}$, so there's no contradiction with Godel here. There is an internal-to-$\mathsf{ZF}$ version, but it's weaker than one might expect: $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $Con(A)$ for each finite $A\subseteq \mathsf{ZF}$, but this isn't saying much since - as far as $\mathsf{ZF}$ knows - $\mathsf{ZF}$ could be inconsistent and hence prove everything.)*

- **Set-theoretic argument**: Given a finite $A\subset\mathsf{ZF}$, let $\alpha_A=\min\{\alpha: V_\alpha\models A\}$. Inside $V_{\alpha_A}$ there is no level of the cumulative hierarchy which satisfies $A$ - so $V_{\alpha_A}$ can't satisfy $\mathsf{ZF}$, since $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that there is such a level.

  - This tacitly used a bit of **absoluteness**, namely with respect to the cumulative hierarchy (for $\beta<\alpha$ we have $V_\beta^{V_\alpha}=V_\beta$) and to first-order satisfaction (for $M\in V_\alpha$ we have $V_\alpha\models(M\models A )$ iff $M\models A$ in reality). These absoluteness facts are true, important, and not hard to prove, but it's a good exercise to show that we can in fact avoid invoking them entirely:

> Suppose $A\subset\mathsf{ZF}$ is finite and axiomatizes $\mathsf{ZF}$. Let $\alpha_0$ be some ordinal such that $V_{\alpha_0}\models A$ and let $M_0=V_{\alpha_0}$. Now having defined $\alpha_i$ and $M_i$, let $\alpha_{i+1}$ be some ordinal $\beta<\alpha_i$ such that $M_i\models (V_{\beta}\models A)$ and let $M_{i+1}=V_{\alpha_{i+1}}^{M_i}$. This defines a descending sequence of ordinals, so it must stop at some point $n$; but then $M_n$ is a model of $A$, hence of $\mathsf{ZF}$, which thinks that no level of the cumulative hierarchy satisfies $A$, contradicting reflection.

- **Proof-theoretic argument**: Suppose $T$ were a finite fragment of $\mathsf{ZF}$ which axiomatizes the whole. By the reflection principle we have $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(T)$; since proofs are finite, there is some finite $S\subset\mathsf{ZF}$ such that $S\vdash Con(T)$. Since $S$ is finite and $T$ axiomatizes all of $\mathsf{ZF}$, we get $T\vdash S$ - the finiteness of $S$ being used to make sure this actually makes sense - and by composing proofs we get $T\vdash Con(T)$, contradicting Godel.

  - Note that there's a seemingly-simpler argument here: since $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(T)$ we must have that $T$ doesn't axiomatize $\mathsf{ZF}$ since otherwise we'd get $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZF})$, contradicting Godel. What's the issue?

> The above relies on $\mathsf{ZF}$ **proving** that $T$ axiomatizes $\mathsf{ZF}$, and this isn't trivial.

---

As a coda, note that no "$L$-flavored" argument will work since there **is** a finite $A\subset\mathsf{ZF}$ such that $L$ is the smallest transitive class containing the ordinals and satisfying $A$. This is basically a consequence of the construction of $L$ via the finitely many [Godel operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_operation). The reflection theorem is very *un*-$L$-flavored in that the models it yields are "short, wide, and (possibly) wild" rather than "tall, thin, and tame."

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit -- yeah, I opted out for a proof using the Levy's formulation of the Reflection Principle, and it nicely fell into place with some of my other arguments about the existence property for ZF